# Listing in React using array.map does not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-10, jsx

I have such code for rendering function:

```
render () {
  return (
    <div className='s-with-fancy-arrow'>
    <select className='city' onChange={this.change} value={this.state.selected}>
    {
      this.state.cities.map(function (city, index) {
        return <option key={'city-list-' + index} value={city.id}>{city.display_name}</option>
      })
    }
    </select>
    </div>
    );
}
```

In Internet Explorer 10 it rendered only like select in div without any options inside select.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: No idea if this is actually your problem, but the .map function of an array returns a new array. 

Maybe give this a try:

this.state.cities = this.state.cities.map( etc. )

That assumes this.state.cities is the list of options you want in the widget.

Comment: Assuming cities is an array, this would not be a good idea because you never want to directly mutate state by calling `this.state.* = *`.

Comment: By your post I'm assuming this is working fine in other browsers? what is the initial value of `this.state.cities`?

Comment: I would also try moving the function call to the opening bracket and removing the whitespace. Like `{this.state.cities.map........}`

Comment: [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n14wmyqe/) works for me in IE10. Are you sure `this.state.cities` is non-empty in IE10? Maybe the problem is in the code that populates the list, not in the render method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hard searching in code we found a simple reason: using fetch and promise without polifills.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
this.state.cities.map(function (city, index) {
        return (<option key={'city-list-' + index} value={city.id}>{city.display_name}</option>)
      })
```

instead of this

```
this.state.cities.map(function (city, index) {
        return <option key={'city-list-' + index} value={city.id}>{city.display_name}</option>
      })
```

Comment: Have you tested this? there shouldn't be any difference.

Comment: Not tested, but I made a habit of returning `(html)` in render method which worked always.

Comment: Me too, but only when there's nested components.

Comment: Ohh, Thank you for the info. I never tried this. (y)